# How to aline left element with right element using html

Tags: html

> I'm trying to make a left element aline with right element using html. This is my code, i'm totally beginner

```
<body>

    <div align="left>       
        <a href="https://www.linkA.com/">Link A</a><br>
        <a href="https://www.linkB.com/">LinkB</a>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div align="right">
        <a href="https://www.linkC.com/">Link C</a><br>
        <a href="https://www.linkD.com/">LinkD</a>
    </div>

    <p align="left">This is a left paragraph</p>
    <p align="right">This is a right paragraph</p>

</body>
```

Comment: I think you want to have Link A and B and left paragraph aligned to left and Link C and D and right paragraph aligned to Right. Both being placed right next to each other.
Well, this is something you can achieve by CSS.
You can use float (old school) or flexbox.

Comment: p has default style `display: block;`, try changing it to `display: inline;`

Comment: **Arsalan Khattak** you're right, that's what i mean actually, i thought i can do aligned using HTML. so, this can be done using CSS ,, thanks

Comment: **zehata** i'll give a try,, thanks